# Change specific block look & feel

Tags: blocks, theming, i18n-l10n

I have a block like this:

```
<section id="block-locale-language" class="block block-locale clearfix" data-thmr="thmr_23">
<h2 class="block-title">Languages</h2>
<ul class="language-switcher-locale-url" data-thmr="thmr_8"><li class="nl first"><a href="/nl/user/1" class="language-link" lang="nl" data-thmr="thmr_9">Nederlands</a></li>
    <li class="en active"><a href="/user/1" class="language-link active" lang="en" data-thmr="thmr_10">English</a></li>
    <li class="fr last"><a href="/fr/user/1" class="language-link" lang="fr" data-thmr="thmr_11">Français</a></li>
</ul>
```

(From the language switcher module)

But now I would like to have something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where do I have to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template file in your theme.

```
block--locale.tpl.php
```

Comment: Ok, I can now change the stuff around the $content. But how can I change the stuff in the $content?